Solved: Finding all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with following property
The problem is :

Finding all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following :
$$ f(x^2 - g(y)) = g(x)^2 - y \quad \quad \forall x, y\in \mathbb{R}. $$

From the shape of the equations, It's easy to see that $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=x$ solves the equation. But I don't know how to prove it.
The following is my attempts for proof.

$x \leftarrow (-x)$ gives
$$ f((-x)^2 - g(y)) = g(-x)^2 - y.$$
From here, we have that $g(x)^2 = g(-x)^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

$y \leftarrow (-y)$ gives
$$ f(x^2 - g(-y)) = g(x)^2 +y. $$
From the fact that $g(y) = \pm g(-y)$, we have that
$$g(y) = -g(-y)\quad \quad \forall y\in \mathbb{R}/\{0\}. $$
and if $g(y_0)=0$ holds for some $y_0$, then $y_0 = 0$.

$x \leftarrow 0$ gives
$$f(-g(y)) = g(0)^2 - y \quad \quad \forall y\in\mathbb{R}. $$
From here, I found that (1) $f$ is surjective, (2) $g$ is injective.

Now consider the two set
$$ A = \{y\ |\ g(y) > 0,\ y\neq 0\}, \ B = \{y\ |\ g(y) < 0,\ y\neq 0\}. $$
Note that $A = -B$ (and vice versa). 
For all $y\in A$, by substituting $x\leftarrow \sqrt{g(y)}$,
$$ f(0) = g(\sqrt{g(y)})^2 - y. $$
For all $y\in B$, by substituting $x\leftarrow \sqrt{-g(-y)}$ and $y\leftarrow (-y)$,
$$ f(0) = g(\sqrt{-g(y)})^2 + y. $$
From here, we have
$$ A\subseteq \{\ y \ge -f(0)\},\ B\subseteq \{\ y \le f(0) \} $$
and since $A\cup B =\mathbb{R}/\{0\}, f(0)\ge 0.$


Here's what I got so far. any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
----------------Edited---------------
Thanks to Martin R, There was a same problem in AoPS :  artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2554593p21856799

On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2554593p21856799

@MartinR Thanks for the reference. should I delete this post?

That is up to you. I could not find a duplicate on this site, so you can leave this open, or post a self-answer. If you use information from that AoPS discussion then don't forget to add a reference (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and try to make it self-contained.
